how to authenticate one port only when squid listens on 2 ports
I want squid to listen to ports 3128 and 3129. I want auth on 3129 and no auth on 3128.
For now I have this config
# auth_param not shown but working

http_port 3128
http_port 3129
acl input_3128 myportname 3128
acl input_3129 myportname 3129
acl authenticated proxy_auth REQUIRED

http_access allow authenticated input_3129
http_access deny input_3129
http_access allow input_3128
http_access deny all

Unfortunately this does not work at all. Squid always require authentication.
example request:
curl -v --proxy http://myproxy.example.com:3128 http://debian.org/

Squid response:
* processing: http://debian.org/
10.1.2.3:3128...
* Connected to myproxy.example.com (10.1.2.3) port 3128
> GET http://debian.org/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: debian.org
> User-Agent: curl/8.2.1
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
< Server: squid/5.9
< Mime-Version: 1.0
< Date: Wed, 23 Oct 2024 10:15:01 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 3511
< X-Squid-Error: ERR_CACHE_ACCESS_DENIED 0
< Vary: Accept-Language
< Content-Language: en
< Proxy-Authenticate: Basic realm="Squid proxy-caching web server"
< X-Cache: MISS from myproxy
< X-Cache-Lookup: NONE from myproxy:3129
< Via: 1.1 myproxy (squid/5.9)
< Connection: keep-alive
<

Question
How to make squid require authentication only on port 3129 ?

When you're using the ACL type myportname, you are relying on the implicit default name, i.e. that your http_port 3128 is really http_port 3128 name=3128 and likewise for port 3129.
Perhaps try using the myport ACL type instead, i.e. acl input_3128 myport 3128 and acl input_3129 myport 3129?
Also, you might try sorting the http_access directives like this:
http_access allow input_3128
http_access allow authenticated input_3129
http_access deny all

That should allow the first http_access line to match any connections incoming to port 3128 without even hinting that authentication might be needed. If that does not match, the second rule will then match connections to port 3129, now with the authentication requirement in effect. The final deny all will catch anything that does not match either of the first two lines; you don't need a separate http_access deny input_3129 line at all.

A few things. I was not aware of the implicit naming ; probably missed that in the doc. thank for the info.myport has been renamed localport. We tried  localport too, but it did not work either. However reordering the http_access, with the non authenticated one first works. I'm not sure I understand why, but this answers the question. Thanks a lot.

As I understand it, the presence of the authenticated ACL on the http_access line triggers the 407 response, and once that response is sent, the proxy will have no way to say "err... never mind, I don't need authentication from you after all". So you get the behavior you want by first accepting the connections to port 3128 without mentioning authentication at all; if the first http_access line matches, no further http_access lines are processed for that connection at all, so the 407 response won't be triggered.

you're a genius. The pb is the authenticated. We must remember that conditions are anded. So my line reads like “If authenticated and .... then accept”, but the second condition is of course never checked, because of logic short-circuit, and everything fails as soon as the authenticated condition is not satisfied ; the port number never get a chance to be tested. If I write the condition in the other way: “if port 3129 and also authenticated, then ok” it is a whole different story. I'll add an answer, just because reading that in a comment is a pain.

@exore I have to admit, it's been so long since I had to work with Squid that I was a little hazy on how combining the ACLs on a single http_access line works in practice, but of course it's a short-circuiting AND for speed optimization. Thanks for a chance to refresh my memory.

@telcoM gave an explanation in the second comment. I post another solution based on this comment.
On a line, all conditions are anded. So the trouble with
http_access allow authenticated input_3129

is that it checks first the authenticated condition. This condition triggers an early 407 answer for any non authenticated connection, whatever the port number.
Now, if I use instead input_3129 authenticated, because of the implicit and, the authenticated condition is tried only when the input_3129 is met. So no early 407. Squid can go on and try the second http_access rule.
http_access allow input_3129 authenticated
http_access allow input_3128
http_access deny all

